# unget() in Java

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to convert this C++ program to Java.

```
double expression();

char token() { 
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
    return ch;
}

double factor() { 
    double val = 0;
    char ch = token();
    if (ch == '(') {
        val = expression();
        ch = token();
        if (ch != ')') {
            std::string error = std::string("Expected ')', got: ") + ch;
            throw std::runtime_error(error.c_str());
        }
    }
    else if (isdigit(ch)) {
        std::cin.unget();
        std::cin >> val;
    }
   else throw std::runtime_error("Unexpected character");
    return val;
}

double term() { 
    int ch;
    double val = factor();
    ch = token();
    if (ch == '*' || ch == '/') {
        double b = term();
        if (ch == '*')
            val *= b;
        else
            val /= b;
    }
    else std::cin.unget(); // here it is
    return val;
}

double  expression() {
    double val = term();
    char ch = token();
    if (ch == '-' || ch=='+') {
        double b = expression();
        if (ch == '+')
            val += b;
        else
            val -= b;
    }
    else std::cin.unget();
    return val;
}
```

The program can evaluate (or simplify) mathematical expressions (i.e. (5+6-(6*2)/3) )
In term(), "unget" the character if the character is equivalent to any digit. But I can't find "unget()" in Java. And I am a little bit confused regarding this "Unget" operation.

**What can I replace with the equivalent of "unget()" in C++ for Java?**

Comment: What is `token`?

Comment: token  has been used  to take input.
```

char token() { 
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: @Dihan Add all the relevant information in your question as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of posting in the comment section.

Comment: `unget` just returns the last read character to the input stream, so that the next read will read that character again. If Java I/O doesn't have such a function you will just have to code it yourself (hint: use a one character buffer which read checks first before doing an actual read, unget simply places a character in that buffer, it's an error to do two ungets in a row, so a one character buffer is all that is required).

Comment: You could also look at [`PushbackInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) or [`PushbackReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PushbackReader.html) and their `unread` methods.

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream` interface in Java supports two methods `mark` and `reset`, subclasses may or may not support them.

```java
if (!stream.markSupported())
  stream = new BufferedInputStream(stream);  // Supports mark/reset

// If a C++ function calls unget(), call mark() before token()
// in a Java function, or let token() call mark(),
// and call reset() instead of unget().
stream.mark();  // Remember current position in stream
// read data, process data
stream.reset();  // Rewind to the remembered position
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use the scanner class to read from console. It can check if for example the next chars on the console are a int, or a given pattern (the math expression) and if so it loads the input.

For example:

```
// Using Scanner for Getting Input from User
String mathematicalOperation = "\([0123456789+-]*\)" ;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(mathematicalOperation);
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
if(in.hasNextInt){ 
   val = in.nextInt();}
else if (in.hasNext(Pattern pattern) ) {
   String expresionRaw = in.next(Pattern pattern);
   val = expreion(expresionRaw);
}
```

Or this : if unget moves the input pointer back then if you are using in java this can be done with the reset() methid of the BufferedReader  class